# Logging in loop

Tags: 16.04, mac, parallels

It seems that my user name changed somehow, now is "Felipe" but since I remember it was "phGalaz" originally. Anyhow, if I use a wrong password the system warn me it's wrong, and then if I enter the right one the log in screen come back after a try to log in that sometime shows me my desktop, sometimes not, and then immediately come back to log in screen.

I've been searching for solutions and found some resources in this site, but all of them require go into some sort of terminal trough control+alt+f3. When I go ahead with control+alt+f6 a new back screen shows up asking me to log in again, but once I enter my credentials it say they are not correct.

Answer (score -1):

Hello I had this problem before and you can solve this by , while you are on the login screen press CTRL, ALT F1. Then apply these commands.

service lightdm stop

sudo su -

cd /usr/local/bin

wget -Nc smxi.org/sgfxi

chmod +x sgfxi

sgfxi

after this just follow the steps that will be shown

This should help, and if it does please approve this answer!

Comment: Hi, thanks. When I press control+alt+f1 nothing happen. Only when I press control+alt+f6, then it ask me for my ubuntu login and password, but it say they are wrong. But they are not.

Comment: ohh then it will say login, so then first write your username without caps then it will ask u for password

Comment: login incorrect D:

Comment: are u sure put ur username first and and correctly? and then password?

Comment: and remember no caps

Comment: the login page shows "Felipe" as username. I'm trying "felipe".

Comment: ohh is it then put Cap F and then put password

Comment: first thing I did. What's going on here?

Comment: okkkk, I got in!!! my username is other nothing about Felipe (I dont get it). Ok so now when I tip sgfxi it say access denied. Any though?

Comment: premission denied

Comment: sorry i missed the chmod, lets see if it works

Comment: is it working?.

Comment: ERROR (254): no supported card found! Exiting script now. What should I do????

Comment: try enabling VT/x through BIOS but u have UEFI so search on internet how to enable VT/x on Mac UEFI

Comment: it seems to be enabled. What else could I do?

Comment: i rise the graphic memory on turned the 3d accelerator off on the parallels settings and it let me log in. Any idea whats going on here?

Comment: maybe it has  something got to do with your graphics drivers.